# How to get records in Andorid (kotlin) where field does not exist in all documents in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want filter for one field that does not exist in all records in my document in firestore.

I'm using Android Kotlin with 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:23.0.3'

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and show what is the exact fields on which you want to do the filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore queries only return documents that are present in the index(es) that are used for that query. Documents that don't have a certain field are **not** present in the index on that field, so can never be returned by queries on that field.

This means there is no way to use a query to do what you want. You'll need to read all documents from the collection and check in your application code whether the field is present.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.orderBy()` function,
From [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data)

> An orderBy() clause also filters for existence of the given field. The
> result set will not include documents that do not contain the given
> field.